# Realm Query which filters dates with datatype String

Tags: android, string, date, filter, realm

I have a Realm Object and I want to create a Query with a filter. My Realm Object has the attribute date. It has the format dd/mm/yyyy and is a String.

I want to create a Query that searches all entries where the date is a date in the future.My problem is that the function `greaterThanOrEquals` doesn't take a String (such as Date) as a parameter.

The result that I'm expecting is the following: Today is 09/07/2017. If an Element has the date of today or some date in future (e.g 10/07/2017), it should be in the result list. If it is in the past, then it should not be in the list.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You should add a date field that is actually a Date and not a String.

Comment: Thanks for your answer good idea, but this solution is because of many reasons not possible for me.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you can do that by having both fields if necessary, although your string can easily be reconstructed via SimpleDateFormat